# Using complete to fill groups with NA to have same length as the maximum group

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L), var = c("A", "B", 
"C", "B", "C", "C")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))

  id var
1  1   A
2  1   B
3  1   C
4  2   B
5  2   C
6  3   C
```

I would like to get this dataframe:

```
  id  var
1  1    A
2  1    B
3  1    C
4  2 <NA>
5  2    B
6  2    C
7  3 <NA>
8  3 <NA>
9  3    C
```

I would like to learn how to use `complete`  or `expand.grid` in this situation

I have tried several ways but was not successful: One of my tries:

```
df %>% 
  complete(id, var, fill=list(NA))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a duplicate column of 'var' and then do the `complete` on the other column, which makes the `NA` in the 'var' column and then remove the duplicate 'var' column

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
df %>% 
   mutate(var1 = var) %>% 
   complete(id, var1) %>% 
   select(-var1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 9 × 2
     id var  
  <int> <chr>
1     1 A    
2     1 B    
3     1 C    
4     2 <NA> 
5     2 B    
6     2 C    
7     3 <NA> 
8     3 <NA> 
9     3 C
```

Comment: ,@akrun: Thanks master. This works perfect. Anyway I would like to apply this solution to this question <https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69636341/splitting-character-with-different-string-lengths-while-keeping-the-positional-m#69636341> My code so far: `tib %>% 
  separate_rows("location", sep = ", ") %>%
  mutate(location1 = location) %>% 
  complete(obs, location1) %>% 
  select(-location1)`

Comment: It does not give the expected result. I think the alphabetical order matters or it is because of using `separate_rows`?

Comment: @TarJae Try using `pivot_wider` i.e. `tib %>%    separate_rows("location", sep = ", ") %>% group_by(obs) %>% mutate(new = rev(c("country", "state", "city")[row_number()])) %>% ungroup %>% pivot_wider(names_from = new, values_from = location)`